# How to touch image button without getview or findViewById on Robotium?

Tags: java, android, robotium, findviewbyid, getview

I'm making auto test script(robotium) for android app (audio player)
but have some problems.

Touch event(getview, findViewById , clickOnView) don't work only when particular object is avaliable on screen.

I don't know what type of object it is... I'm not developer and I don't know about Java.

touch event test script like this

```
        Button button = (Button)solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(com.packname.mirror.R.id.bt_menu);

        solo.clickOnView(button);
```

Also android debug monitor can't dump view hierarchy when that particular object is available on screen - (Error obtaining UI hierarchy
Error while parsing UI hierarchy XML file: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file.)

so, I think getview, findViewById do not work only when particular object is available on the screen.

It seems need to find a way to touch image buttons without using getview or findViewById

Can't use axis touch method... many linear layout objects in app.
That cause problem when testing on various resolution devices.

In short, How to touch image button without getview or findViewById on Robotium ?

I don't have source but I have only **R.java** source(R.java maybe helping about it?)

please help me

(sorry for my bad English)